# How to find initial function of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, problem-solving

I am stuck in this problem. How do I find the initial function of a given function? I am learning integral and there in the formula $S=F(b)-F(a)$ is $F$ the initial function of $f$. For example, $f(x)=x^2$, one of its initial functions can be $F(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{3}$. This is what my textbook says but I don't know how this comes and how I can find the initial functions of other functions. :(.

Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule that your textbook is using is that an antiderivative (what you call the initial function) of $x^n$ is $\frac{1}{n + 1}x^{n + 1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Besides to @Jim's answer, you may find an anti-derivatives of the following elementary functions: $$\text{e}^{ax},~~~\cos(bx),~~~\sin(bx),~~~ x^k$$ by using the derivation well-known formulas and some elementary per-calculus formulas. And may be you cannot find the initial functions via this approach. For example, you can find the anti-derivative functions of $\cos(2x)$ and $\exp(-5x)$ which are $\frac{1}2\sin(2x)$ and $\frac{1}{-5}\text{e}^{-5x}$ respectively; **but** without using some certain methods you may not able to find the anti-derivative of $\cos(2x)\exp(-5x)$ just by applying the differentiation formulas.

Comment: yeah, e.g. to find the initial function of $\sqrt{x^3+1}$ is also hard, isnot it?

Comment: Just by guessing and using derivation formulas it is a bit difficult to be solved. It really needs a certain method.

Comment: so, theres been no certain method by now?

Comment: @doniyor: See this http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Differential_binomial for above integral.

Comment: Hello, dear friend!

Comment: I am doing well. You too, make me glad! How are you doing? :+)

Comment: @amWhy: It goes 50/50. not good not bad. Sometimes I want to think about every questions here but it takes time and so I cannot. I feel Mathematics becomes my wife, any way :D xD

Comment: I completely understand! I find myself rethinking questions and answers as I try and do other things, like when trying to fall asleep! It does seem, at times, as though mathematics "consumes" me!

Comment: @amWhy: Like a Black Hole! Just consumes us ;-)